# What's this "Finder" icon on my Desktop and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, desktop

A few days ago, this icon appeared on my desktop. It sticks near the top-right of the screen and it doesn't seem like I can reposition it. Clicking on it has no effect.

[image]

In Mission Control, the icon changes to look like this:

[image]

How do I get rid of it?

I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 on a 2014 MacBook Pro.

Comment: Can you try relaunching the Finder app. Go to Apple Menu → Force Quit... (or press Option + Command + Esc). In the Force Quit Applications window that appears, click on Finder and then click on Relaunch button. See if that gets rid of the tiny window.

Comment: is that only in Desktop 2 window

Comment: @NimeshNeema Yes it went away after that. Thank you!

Comment: @user2121620 This question did just get bumped to the home page because you haven't accepted the answer that you say solved the problem. Please do so now, not only to show your appreciation but so the question can be laid to rest. That's how the stackexchange system works. (Note to others seeing this: The user seems to come visiting only rarely, so be patient.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relaunch the Finder app to get rid of the tiny window.

Go to Apple Menu → Force Quit... or press <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>. In the Force Quit Applications window that appears, click on **Finder** and then click on **Relaunch** button.

It will get rid of the tiny window.